# SBT native packager: reference to undefined setting Universal / mappings

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using the sbt-native-packager to build my Docker image and publish it to my local. I have a custom directory where I have some files that I would like to be part of the resulting Docker file system. I have tried the following in my build.sbt:

```
Universal / mappings += (file("data/housing.tgz"), "/opt/docker/data/housing.tgz")
```

But this results in an error as below:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.7 (Private Build Java 1.8.0_312)
[info] loading settings for project housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/project
[info] loading settings for project housing-price-prediction-data-preparation from build.sbt ...
[info] resolving key references (10159 settings) ...
Reference to undefined setting: 

  Universal / mappings from Universal / mappings (/home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/build.sbt:58)
 
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.Uninitialized(Settings.scala:419)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.Uninitialized$(Settings.scala:406)
    at sbt.Def$.Uninitialized(Def.scala:24)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.delegate(Settings.scala:313)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.delegate$(Settings.scala:275)
    at sbt.Def$.delegate(Def.scala:24)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.compiled(Settings.scala:200)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.compiled$(Settings.scala:187)
    at sbt.Def$.compiled(Def.scala:24)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.makeWithCompiledMap(Settings.scala:217)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.makeWithCompiledMap$(Settings.scala:212)
    at sbt.Def$.makeWithCompiledMap(Def.scala:24)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$5(Load.scala:263)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1393)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:255)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:56)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:959)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:959)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:912)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:150)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:145)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:189)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$processCommand$5(MainLoop.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:245)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:278)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$5(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:289)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:325)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$4(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:163)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:144)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:119)
    at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:27)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:112)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:51)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:42)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:218)
    at sbt.xMain$.$anonfun$run$11(Main.scala:133)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withIn(Console.scala:230)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withIn(Terminal.scala:569)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withStreams$1(Terminal.scala:350)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:167)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withOut$2(Terminal.scala:559)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withErr(Console.scala:196)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withOut(Terminal.scala:559)
    at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withStreams(Terminal.scala:350)
    at sbt.xMain$.withStreams$1(Main.scala:87)
    at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.java:56)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:46)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   Universal / mappings from Universal / mappings (/home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/build.sbt:58)
[error]  
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

Isn't like this how I should be adding additional folders? What is causing this error?

My plugins.sbt has the following:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.9.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.9")
```

Comment: What does your `plugins.sbt` contains?

Comment: I have edited my post with the contents of my plugins.sbt